# How to send string as a input field value of a website?

Tags: dart, http, console-application

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('https://bitwarden.com/password-strength/'));
  final document = parse(response.body);

  final searchBox = document.querySelector('.css-35zt5t')!;
  final query = 'Hello*World123';
  // searchBox value is not updating hence getting the same result as very week
  searchBox.innerHtml = query;

  // parent element tha'll have the result once the query is posted
  var parent = document.querySelector('.css-189dhzu')!;
  // only div element that'll have the result
  var divElement = parent.querySelector('div');

  if (divElement != null && divElement.text.isNotEmpty) {
    print(divElement.text);
  } else {
    print('Div element not found or has no text content');
  }
}
```

The code probably not pushing the value to the input field of website. Found a way but it uses dart:html pkg which is not supported in console application. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: changing a local view of your HTML won't mean any server changes.  You need to work out what PUT or POST call needs to be generate to trigger server-side actions.